# Identity theorem for (real) analytic functions on lower dimensional subsets

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, complex-analysis, functions, continuity

For simplicity, we will deal with $\mathbb{R}^2$. Let's assume we have an one-dimensional submanifold $M_1 \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ and two analytic function $F,G: M_1 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$.

If I know $$F|_{M_1}=G|_{M_1}$$
Can I conclude $F|_{\mathbb{R}^2}=G|_{\mathbb{R}^2}$?

---

I think this is not possible, since the uniqueness theorem is not applicable on $M_1$ since it is an one dimensional submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and hence closed.

Is it maybe possible if they agree on the subset I have drawn below? (Two one dimensional submanifolds intersecting in one point)
[image]

Comment: $x=0$ is a line and $xy=0$ is two lines etc but $x$ is not the zero function, nor is $xy$ and both are real analytic

Comment: @Conrad do you want to post that as an answer?